# How load custom bash aliases in NodeJS script?

Tags: node.js, bash, alias

I have bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s expand_aliases
. my_custom_aliases # load aliases
alias foo # show alias definition
foo # run alias
```

and it's working as I want

```
$ ./alias.sh 
alias foo='echo barrr'
barrr
```

but now I would like to do the same thing in nodejs script.

I've try something like this with ShellJS package

```
#! /usr/bin/env node
var shell = require("shelljs");
shell.exec('shopt -s expand_aliases', {shell: '/bin/bash'});
shell.exec('. my_custom_aliases', {shell: '/bin/bash'});
shell.exec('alias foo', {shell: '/bin/bash'});
shell.exec('foo', {shell: '/bin/bash'});
```

*(`my_custom_aliases` obviously are in the same directory)*

but it's only throwing on me this

```
$ node am.js 
/bin/bash: line 0: alias: foo: not found
/bin/bash: foo: command not found
```

So my question is: How can I load custom aliases from file and be able to use them from inside the node script?

Comment: In theory, couldn't you just load and read the bash script, and execute it with nodeJS?

Comment: I would expect every `shell.exec()` to run in a new shell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not convinced that you are doing sane things (if you really do, functions might be better than aliases anyway), but the problem is that you are running four separate shells, each of which then exits and loses whatever state you had created.

To run a single shell, you want something like

```
shell.exec('shopt -s expand_aliases \n . my_custom_aliases \n alias foo; foo',
  {shell: '/bin/bash'});
```

As outlined in comments below, because `expand_aliases` needs to be active when a line with an alias is first parsed, you need a newline rather than a semicolon as the first and second statement separator.

Comment: `alias foo` is working now but running `foo` no. 
/bin/bash: foo: command not found

Comment: Is there a chance to run this in separate commands? I wont extend this script and use much more then just this one alias. It would be great to have capabilities like in bash where I don't need to run this in one looooooong line.

Comment: Having the command(s) in a script file would seem to make more sense anyway. Aliases are only a meant as a convenience for interactive use.

Comment: Oh, I think I recall now that the alias won't be expanded if it's the same physical line, because `expand_aliases` needs to be enabled when the line is originally parsed. Try with newlines instead of semicolons.

Comment: And that's my purpose. I want to maniputlate aliases via node script. I want to be able to manipulate aliases in current shell context. E.g.: `node addalias.js` will add to my current bash context (instance) an alias that I can use it (interactive mode).

Comment: if You dont source `my_custom_aliases` in seperate line it's doesn't work either

Comment: Thanks for noting, and sorry I wasn't able to test this myself.